# Maputnik with custom tile server (auth)

Tags: vector-tiles, mapbox-gl-js, tile-server, maputnik

I have a private vector tile server with authentication in place, at the moment I am trying to set up a solution to generate my own styles for mapbox-gl-js. While investigating options I found Maptunik and it looks like a really good tool, but I need a way to pass my authentication header to the requests made to my custom source, I saw that is supports adding authentication tokens from Mapbox and other sources but I need a way to add the a header for my own. Is there a way to do this?